# How can I re-try a property-based-test if the randomly-generated inputs are not useful?

Tags: .net, f#, nunit, fscheck, property-based-testing

I am a n00b to unit testing. I have installed `FsCheck.Nunit` and `NUnitTestAdapter` from Nuget, and I'm trying to do property-based-testing, largely inspired by [the inestimable Scott Wlaschin](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/property-based-testing/).

I am using the `[<Property>]` attribute, and I would like the ability to "skip" inputs that don't meet the test's requirements:

```
[<Property(MaxTest=10)>]
let ``Calling unzipTo with an invalid destination will yield a failure.`` badDest =
    if Directory.Exists(badDest)
    then // somehow skip to the next randomized input
    else // do the actual test
```

**What's the simplest way to do this?**

I would prefer an answer for FsCheck/NUnit if it exists, but I would also consider any other framework whose tests can be run in Visual Studio. (I thought I saw some framework where there was a simple function to do exactly this, but I can't figure out what it was.)

I have preferred FsCheck.NUnit so far because it can generate random inputs for F# types (discriminated unions, etc) without additional work.

Comment: You need a custom generator.

Comment: IIRC for the then statement you only have to return the result that states the test succeeded without running the test. Something as simple as `true` might work. I ran into this years back and the problem was overthinking the problem. Remember the test is just a function and the test driver just wants a result indicating success or failure so give it a success.

Comment: @Guy Coder The rub is that I want the test to be re-run with different random inputs if the generated ones are not useful -- I don't want the function to run many times with unsuitable inputs and declare itself a success if it never actually performed its test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit

[<Property(MaxTest=10)>]
let ``Calling unzipTo with an invalid destination will yield a failure.`` badDest =
    (not Directory.Exists(badDest)) ==> lazy
    // do the actual test
```

The first line is a boolean condition, and `==>` is a custom operator defined by the `FsCheck` module. It'll only force evaluation of the lazy expression if the condition on the right-hand side evaluates to `true`.

Do consider, however, refactoring this test so that it doesn't depend on the file system. The file system is persistent, so that automatically creates a Persistent Fixture, which is [a lot of trouble to manage](http://xunitpatterns.com/Persistent%20Fixture%20Management.html); not impossible to deal with, but better avoided.

This example uses *FsCheck.Xunit*, but IIRC *FsCheck.Nunit* works the same way. You should seriously consider using *FsCheck.Xunit* instead of *FsCheck.Nunit*, though. The extensibility model of NUnit 2 is extraordinarily poor, which means that most Glue Libraries that attempt to extend NUnit come with lots of problems. This isn't a problem with *FsCheck.Nunit*, but with NUnit itself, but it'll manifest itself in lots of trouble for you.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. I probably saw it on your blog in the first place. Thanks for the tip on NUnit vs Xunit as well.

Comment: Normally I try to keep tests independent of the file system, DB state, etc, but for the functions I'm developing here, manipulating the file system is their primary purpose. How else can I test them at all?

Comment: @OverlordZurg Perhaps this answer answers that question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/99290/3878 ... or perhaps it doesn't :)

Answer (score 1):

`FsCheck.Prop.discard()` seems to do what I want -- when I run the test with logging, I can see that some attempts were discarded, but 10 runs were completed without being discarded.

The `==>` operator works for running the tests with `FsCheck.Quick` or similar. However, that requires the lazy part to be in the format of 'Testable, where the tests I'm currently writing are just `<inputs>->unit`.

Comment: *"that requires the lazy part to be in the format of 'Testable"* That ought not to be a problem. The compiler will infer the appropriate type for you. See here for examples: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/09/08/ad-hoc-arbitraries-with-fscheckxunit

Comment: Calling `discard` in your `then` branch, or using the approach with `==>` should be completely equivalent. Though `==>` is the preferred approach - it reads better imo and`discard` works by throwing and catching an exception under the hood, so may be slow and disruptive for debugging.

Comment: Found the problem - I was trying to return unit, but I needed to return bool. Unfortunately, returning bool from the lazy part (rather than Assert.AreEqual()) loses me the nice formatting that explicitly states expected vs. actual value. I am continuing to explore options, but at least I understand now  :)

Comment: w.r.t my previous comment, the thought (eventually) occurs that I can call Assert.Whatever(), which throws an exception if not satisfied, and then just return "true" at the end to achieve the same result (helpful formatting on error).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with F# or fscheck, but NUnit provides the [`Assert.Ignore()`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Assert.Ignore) function, which will immediately stop the test and marked it as "ignored."  You could also use [`Assert.Inconclusive()`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Assert.Inconclusive) or [`Assert.Pass()`](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Assert.Pass) if you felt those were more appropriate statuses.

Comment: I have tried "Assert.Ignore()", but that causes tests marked with the [<FsCheck.NUnit.Property>] attribute to fail, which is not the behaviour I want.